# PhantomJS rewriting URL in backgroundImage property to local file system

Tags: phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to do some rewriting of HTML. I'm adding a `background-image` property to an element. But when I write out the resulting DOM, the URL has been rewritten to a local URL. I've boiled this down to the following test case:

**JS**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open("test.html",function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        page.evaluate(function(){
            document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundImage="url(test.png)";
        });
        console.log(page.content);
        phantom.exit();
   },1000);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output**

```
$ phantomjs test.js
<html><head></head><body>
    <div id="test" style="background-image: url(file:///C:/cygwin/tmp/test.png); ">
    </div>  
</body></html>
```

**UPDATE**

1. The problem remains if you specify `./test.png` or `//test.png`. However, `http://example.com/test.png` is left unchanged, as might be expected.
2. If this HTML document is opened in Chrome, and the `background-image` property added to the `div` element in the style inspector, the URL is unmodified, whether the document is inspected in the Elements tab in devtools, or via `document.body.innerHTML` displayed in the console, or copying the HTML.

**UPDATE 2**

I just found out that if the document is located in Chrome, and the command `elt.style.backgroundImage="url(test.png");` is issued in the console, then the URL is rewritten. So at the end of the day it appears that this is not a PhantomJS issue, although I still don't understand this behavior.

Obviously, I don't want this URL to be rewritten in this fashion, and I don't understand why PhantomJS feels the need to do this. Ideas?

Comment: I bet you would see the same thing in a normal browser.  Have you tried it in Chrome?

Comment: This is indeed odd and I would have expected to see such behaviour _outside_ of the `page.evaluate()` yet it is _inside_ the sandbox. What happens if you provide an absolute URL (e.g. `https://www.google.co.uk/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png`)?

Comment: this sounds like a PhantomJS bug to me, please report the issue to their Git.

Comment: Reported at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11567.